# How to update oov word embedding in keras

Tags: keras

In my model of calculating sentence semantic similarity. I use glove pretrained word embedding. But there are many words not in this pretrained model. I want to fix the embedding of words in glove and learn the embedding of these words not appearing in glove. How to do this in Keras?

Comment: Maybe you could use your own embedding, leaving glove aside.

Comment: But I want to fix the embedding of words in glove. I have tried to let all words' embedding trainable. But my train data is very small comparing to glove. It can't improve the final performance but adding more computing complexity.